# facebook open graph - Photo uploading

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am upgrading my apps to open graph.
I am not able to clearly get the photo uploading docs in open graph except user_generated property.

I tried **fb:explicitly_shared = true** but image has been uploaded in 90*90
But when i try to use **user_generated = true** i got the image in real size.

But there are some conditions to use user_generated property.
How do we upload a photo in bigger size using open graph without using user_generated property?

I tried reading the docs many times. I am really not able to find it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to facebook's gudelines user generated photos are those that are taken by mobile's camera.So you won't be able to post the bigger picture.
But you can post a 196X196 px image  by using og:image meta tag in the object webpage.